# how can disable a textbox in class asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, textbox, disabled-control

```
 private void txtenable (Boolean txtenable)
 {
     if(txtenable== false)
     {
         txtname.Enabled = false;
         txtTel.Enabled = false;
         txtmobile.Enabled = false;
         txtAdress.Enabled = false;
      }
      else
      {
           txtname.Enabled = true;
          txtTel.Enabled = true;
          txtmobile.Enabled = true;
          txtAdress.Enabled = true;
      }

 }
```

I want use this class but i can not call textboxes. How can call textbox in class?

Comment: You have given only method here. Please provide whole class. Also if possible, mention exact requirements what you are looking for?

Comment: i want create a class like up class

Comment: but in class how can call textbox

Comment: i write this code in notepad just notepad no in asp.net  .......  ok?

Comment: Well in one line I can say, when you create object of that class, call this method. And while calling method pass your textbox as a reference. That way you can access your textbox.

Comment: can you create an Example   like UP  ?

Comment: You could just write `txtname.Enabled = txtenable;` for all 4 textboxes since `txtenable` is a boolean, Saves 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to be able to accept the TextBox objects within the class, then you can manipulate them how you see fit. I haven't actually tried this, but this is how I would go about setting it up.

```
public class YourClass
{
TextBox txtName; 
TextBox txtTel;
TextBox txtMobile;
TextBox txtAddress;
private void txtenable (Boolean txtenable, TextBox txtName, TextBox txtTel, TextBox txtMobile, TextBox txtAddress)
 {
 if(txtenable== false)
 {
     txtName.Enabled = false;
     txtTel.Enabled = false;
     txtMobile.Enabled = false;
     txtAddress.Enabled = false;
  }
  else
  {
      txtName.Enabled = true;
      txtTel.Enabled = true;
      txtMobile.Enabled = true;
      txtAddress.Enabled = true;
  }

}
```

In order for you to access the textboxes from within your class you will need to pass them such as:

```
public class OtherClassContainingTextBoxes
{
private void SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e){
txtenable(true, txtName, txtTel, txtMobile, txtAddress);
}
```

However, based on the example provided, I am unsure why you wouldn't do this in a method within the class you have your textboxes.

You could do something on pageload:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (Session["enable"] == false){
       txtenable(false);
    }else{
      txtenable(true);
    }
 } 
private void txtenable (Boolean txtenable)
 {
     if(txtenable== false)
 {
         txtName.Enabled = false;
         txtTel.Enabled = false;
         txtMobile.Enabled = false;
         txtAddress.Enabled = false;
}
     else
     {
         txtName.Enabled = true;
         txtTel.Enabled = true;
         txtMobile.Enabled = true;
         txtAddress.Enabled = true;
      }

 }
```